# How to hide or remove <li> from C# code behind

Tags: c#

From my code behind I am adding set of `<li>` from a loop. Like this :

```
foreach (var item in optionalOrderItems)
{
    var itemDetails = calculatedItems.Details
                                     .Where(d => d.ItemCode == item.ItemCode)
                                     .FirstOrDefault();
    if (itemDetails == null)
        continue;

    articleContent.Append(string.Format(@"
            <li>
                <span class='quantity'><span class='label'>{0:N0}</span></span>
                <span class='description' style='width:110px;'>{1}</span>  " +
                (show ? @"<span class='description' style='width:60px;text-align:right;'>({5:N0} {6})</span>  "
                      : "") +
                @"<a href="" javascript:Enrollment.Shopping.DeleteItem('{2}','{4}', 'order');"" class='close {3}' style='line-height:28px;' title='Remove'>&times;</a>
                <div class='clear'></div>
            </li>",
        itemDetails.Quantity,
        itemDetails.Description,
        itemDetails.ItemCode,
        (!allowItemModifications) ? "hidden" : string.Empty,
        item.Type,
        itemDetails.Other2Each * item.Quantity,
        Content.CommonLabelPV));

    subtotal = subtotal + itemDetails.PriceEach*itemDetails.Quantity;
}
```

But on one of my condition I want to remove one of the `<li>` from code behind.

So my question is: how to remove particular `<li>` from code behind?

Comment: Check the condition before adding it?  If the condition fails, don't add that one.  It's not clear exactly what the problem is here.

Comment: Actually first time I need to add but for some reason if customer delete 1 of the item and there total is less than 100 then i need to remove one particular item..how can i do that from code behind

Comment: @David I think that what he needs to remove it after it was added, maybe on certain conditions between postbacks ?

Comment: Please format your code snippet

Comment: I am doing it with ajax..so if customer delete 1 item and then i need to hide or delete there ffree promotional item

Comment: If this is bound to the state of a collection of data which changes between post-backs then I recommend using a data-bound control to handle that.  Something as simple as a `Repeater` can hold the custom client-side code that you have and just repeat that code for items in a collection.  When the user modifies the collection, the `Repeater` is updated automatically.

Comment: @user207888: Then it's not clear at all where the issue is.  If you're "doing it with AJAX" then are you even in the context of a code-behind at that time?  Shouldn't you be removing the item from the display with client-side code?

Answer (score 0):

To the main question, you can't.

You remove by JavaScript or not add when populating list in C#.

In some conditions you can with [ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), after a post:

JS:

```
function removeLI(){
    $([li]).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what David put in his comments, just check the condition and don't do it if it fails.

```
if (itemDetails == null || SOMEOTHERTRUESTATEMENT)
    continue;
```

Comment: Based on your comments, I think you mean client side and not code behind.